# Calculo de pacotes

Tags: php

tenho a seguinte expressão:

```
 $pacotes = intval($_peso / 30) + 1;
```

A ideia é saber quantos pacotes iguais dará.

Por exemplo: se eu tenho um `$_peso` de `29kg`, dividos por `30kgs` (máximo permitido pelos correios), terei um resultado de `0,96666666666666666666666666666667`. Por tanto, menor que 1. Nesse caso, estou pegando o valor inteiro (0) e somando 1. Afinal não existe `0 pacote`.

Mas quando o $_peso dá exatamente 30, 60, 90, etc...... tenho problemas pois

```
  30/30 = 1. 
  1+1=2
```

E não são necessários `2 pacotes`.

Como resolver essa lógica?

Será que terei que pegar o valor de `topo`? Ou seja, se der `1,2 pacotes` serão `2 pacotes` e se derem `0,8 pacote`s será `1 Pacote`?

Se sim, como pegar o `topo` (inverso da base) de um valor em php?

Comment: No caso você queria pegar o resultado para $pacotes (antes de adicionar o +1) e simplesmente arredondar ele para cima ? Já tentou fazer assim?

Comment: Já descobri.Na verdade depois que digitei a pergunta acabei lembrando das paginações de resultado  Preciso da função ceil(). Obrigado!

Comment: Mas e nos casos de 30, 60 e 90? Essa função atende também?

Comment: com certeza atende

Comment: @CarlosRocha, seria interessante você adicionar a resposta que você mesmo encontrou e marcar como correta. Não há nenhum problema em responder as próprias perguntas: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Comment: Concordo! Esta feito!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desenvolvi uma classe que me auxilia.

Digamos que a encomenda, que possa ser dobrada é claro, pese por exemplo `55kg`.

Os `correios` só levam `30kg`. Logo, posso `dividir em 2 pacotes`(menores que 30kg).

No caso, pegando `57` e fazendo `ceil(57/30)` terei o arredondamento (sempre para cima), do número de pacotes necessários de no máximo `30kg` cada.

No caso, `57/30 = 1.9`, arredondando para cima com `ceil()` teremos 2 pacotes.

Então, fazemos `57 kg / 2 pacotes` =  `2 pacotes de 28,5kg cada`.

Fazemos o cálculo do frete para `1 pacote` e multiplicamos pelo número de pacotes e apresentamos ao cliente.

```
<?php

 class CalculaFrete {

  //Sedex: 40010
  //Pac: 41106   

  private $url = "http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.aspx?";
  private $precoPacote = 5;
  private $pesoPacote = 0.2;
  private $cepOrigem;
  private $cepDestino;
  private $peso;
  private $valor;
  private $tipoFrete;
  private $altura = 6;
  private $largura = 20;
  private $comprimento = 20;
  private $quantosPacotes;
  private $erro;

  public function __construct (
    $_cepDestino,
    $_peso,
    $_valor,
    $_tipoFrete
  ) {
      $pacotes = ceil($_peso / 30);

      $this->cepDestino = $_cepDestino;
      $this->peso = $_peso / $pacotes;
      $this->valor = $_valor;
      $this->tipoFrete = $_tipoFrete;
      $this->quantosPacotes = $pacotes;
      $this->cepOrigem  = $constantes->getCepSite();
  }

  public function getPrecoPacote () {

      return $this->precoPacote;
  }

  public function getPesoPacote () {

      return $this->pesoPacote;
  }

  public function getPacotes () {

      return $this->quantosPacotes;
  }

  public function getPeso () {

      return $this->peso;
  }

  public function getErro () {

      return $this->erro;
  }

  public function calcularFrete() {   

      $url = $this->url;
      $url .= "nCdEmpresa=";
      $url .= "&sDsSenha=";
      $url .= "&sCepOrigem=" . $this->cepOrigem;
      $url .= "&sCepDestino=" . $this->cepDestino;
      $url .= "&nVlPeso=" . $this->peso;
      $url .= "&nVlLargura=" . $this->largura;
      $url .= "&nVlAltura=" . $this->altura;
      $url .= "&nCdFormato=1";
      $url .= "&nVlComprimento=" . $this->comprimento;
      $url .= "&sCdMaoProria=n";
      $url .= "&nVlValorDeclarado=" . $this->valor;
      $url .= "&sCdAvisoRecebimento=n";
      $url .= "&nCdServico=" . $this->tipoFrete;
      $url .= "&nVlDiametro=0";
      $url .= "&StrRetorno=xml";     

      $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

      $this->erro = $xml->cServico->Erro;

      return $xml->cServico;

  }

 }
?>
```

A implementação:

```
<?php

      $pesoTotal = 0;
      $precoTotal = 0;

      foreach($_SESSION["carrinho"] as $key => $produto) {
          $pesoTotal += $produto["peso"] * $produto["quantidade"];
          $precoTotal += $produto["precoUnitario"] * $produto["quantidade"];
      }

      $frete = new CalculaFrete($phpUtil->limpaCaracters($_POST["cep"]), $pesoTotal, $precoTotal, 41106);
      $freteValor = $frete->calcularFrete();

      $precoPacote = $frete->getPrecoPacote();
      $pacotes = $frete->getPacotes();
      $peso = $frete->getPeso();

      $valorFrete = $pacotes * (str_replace(",", ".", $freteValor->Valor) + $precoPacote);    

      $valorFinal = $precoTotal + $valorFrete;
?>

É isso!
```

Comment: Concordo e já alterei. Vê se ficou bom!

Comment: Bem melhor. De qq forma eu já tinha votado positivo antes, mas a melhoria pode ajudar a atrair mais votos, e tem mais chance de ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema.

Comment: valeu: $objetivo->ajudarPessoas(); instanciada a classe. rsrs